# What is the kernel width of the gdalwarp resampling methods?

Tags: gdalwarp, resampling

[gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) provides 7 resampling methods. 
How many neighborhood pixels do contribute to **upsampling** respectively **downsampling**?

I will try to guess. Please correct, if values are wrong:

1. Upsampling:

   - near: 1
   - bilinear: 4 (one time around my new resampled pixel)
   - cubic: 4 + 12 (two times around my new resampled pixel)
   - cubicspline: 4 + 12
   - lanczos: 4 + 12
   - average: 4 + 12
   - mode: 4 + 12
2. Downsampling:

   - near: 1
   - bilinear: ?
   - cubic: ?
   - cubicspline: ?
   - lanczos: ?
   - average: ?
   - mode: ?

Downsampling is different, then upsampling. A clever downsampling algorithm would use a bigger Kernel width, if downsampling factor is bigger then 2.

Comment: Hi, did you find out an answer to your question?